# LDAP Get Groups Beginning With

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have a situation whereby Active Directory groups are prefixed with a unique code. For instance

1. 12345 Users
2. 12345 Admins
3. 67890 Users
4. 67890 Admins

I'm currently using LDAP to get all groups but I would like to restrict this to only those prefixed with  the id.

Effectively get groups beginning with 12345.

How can I achieve this with LDAP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using LDAP a filter like:

```
&((ObjectClass=Group)(cn=12345*))
```

Will retrieve  groups beginning with 12345.
-jim

Comment: Pieter - I did rewrite the answer, but I do believe the question was answered. As LDAP is a protocol the method used to obtain the results with the LDAP filter specified would work.

Comment: I believe there is a missing left parenthesis at the beginning. `(&(ObjectClass=Group)(cn=12345*))`